# Serve JSON Download with Node.JS [No 3rd party modules]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I have a JSON File, I use Node.js using localhost, to parse the JSON File and I then use `res.end(JSON.stringify(JSobject))` to send it to my front-end JS script which displays on the DOM using AJAX.

But I want to add a feature where the user can click a download button and instead of sending the JSON file using `res.end(JSON.stringify(JSobject))`, I want the file to download to the user's computer. How can I do this? I only want to use Node.Js, no express etc..

EDIT: I am also open to using other things than AJAX in the front-end

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to download, you would need the button to be a href (not ajax). Whatever this href url points to would need to have headers set so the browser knows what to do, for example: Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=yourfile.ext

Comment: Can you help me by providing some code? Like what do i have to write on the .html file and also what do I have to add on the server.js file?

Comment: Are you using Express.js?

Comment: The poster stated "only want to use Node.Js, no express etc..". He is not using Express.js

Comment: Hi Ben - I am no expert in Node so will not offer any code solutions for you, however, simply searching 'download file with Node.js' turned up a lot of useful results, including the Node documentation itself. Many results were for Node and Express, so perhaps it might be worth considering looking into express as an option.